# a strong factorization system on $\mathbf{Set}$

Tags: category-theory

Does there exist a strong factorization system on $\mathbf{Set}$ i.e. one w.f.s. in which the
liftings are unique ? What are all the possibilities for these strong factorization systems ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $(Epi, Mono)$ is such an example. Try to prove the axioms, it's pretty instructive! (I'm not sure about the fact that you might need some form of axiom of choice)

As for the question how to find "all" WFS on a category, I think it's an open problem even in smaller, simpler categories than $Set$.

But I'd be glad to learn I'm wrong!

Comment: I think that you are wrong! see [this](https://www.matem.unam.mx/~omar/notes/modelcatsets.html).

Comment: A model category structure on Set is a different kind of thing :) it's two interacting WFS. And yes, there surely are just nine model structures on $Set$. But the problem of classifying all _orthogonal_ FS, instead, is different. Just to give an example of how complex the situation can be: every set of morphisms $S \subset \hom({\sf Set})$ generates a prefactorization system, i.e. a pair of orthogonal classes $({}^\perp S, ({}^\perp S)^\perp)$ and $({}^\perp(S^\perp), S^\perp)$. (cntd)

Comment: (cntnd) ... Establishing when is it the case that these two prefactorization systems are actually factorization systems, is a difficult matter.

Comment: A very instructive reading is this classical paper by Bousfield: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82479252.pdf Have a look! As an aside comment: the theory of factorization systems is huge. I spent four years studying a very special class of such systems, and yet I know I just scratched the surface of the topic :-) on the plus side, very basic questions are still an open matter! You're likely to contribute, and I invite you to do so, it's a beautiful piece of category theory

Comment: Certainly no choice is needed for this! The liftings are canonical-that's the beauty of a strong factorization system.

Comment: @user122424's link proceeds by classifying all weak factorization systems on sets and then classifying which pairs give rise to a model structure, so it does solve the problem that was asked, and much more besides.

Comment: It classifies the weak ones, yes. What about the orthogonal ones?

Comment: @Fosco You can just pick the orthogonal factorization systems out of the list of WFSs by hand: other than epi-mono and the trivial ones all-iso and iso-all, one only has one more example: (bij or empty domain)-(any with nonempty domain or identity of $\emptyset$.)